# how to fixed admin url in magento

Tags: magento

I am facing a error in magento admin url

when i write this on my url bar:

http://localhost/cogito/admin

generate  this error on url bar

**http://127.0.0.1/MGT/cogito/admin/admin/index/index/key/99b1b0dea97323ea1f6571637e3239cae3014dff843b90b335286daf9531dd45/?SID=3cgd7072j3nd8i5n0ur2s6toh0**

Answer (score 0):

change value of  "*web/unsecure/base_url*" and "*web/secure/base_url*" to "**http://localhost/cogito/**" in  "core_config_data" table

Comment: is it work magento frontend end ? e.g http://localhost/MGT/cogito/

Please share path of your project directory .I think you installed magento in MGT/cogito  folder .in case you try base_url  **http://localhost/MGT/cogito/**

Answer (score 0):

There must be htaccess issue.
Can you please check if there is a .htaccess file in your root folder?
If not please download it and save and then check your admin url.
Also check the permissions and user of your Project.